# x86 real mode: move data from one array to another

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, real-mode

Here is my code:

```
data segment
gio db 1,2,3,4,5,6
ricxvi db 1
jami db 0
x db ?
ends

stack segment
    db   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:   
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX


     mov cx, 6
     lea si, gio
     mov ah, 0


     n1:
     mov al, [si]
     cmp ricxvi, 3
     je n2
     jmp n3

     n2:
     add jami, al
     mov ricxvi, 1
     jmp n4

     n3:
     add ricxvi, 1
     push ax

     n4:
     add si, 1
     add di, 1
     loop n1




     mov ricxvi, 1
     mov ax, 0
     mov cx, 6
     lea si, gio       


     n5:
     cmp ricxvi, 3
     je n6
     jmp n7


     n6:
     mov ricxvi, 1
     add si, 1
     loop n5

     n7:
     pop [si]
     add si, 1
     loop n5




mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  

ends

end start
```

I have a array named `gio` And I'm trying to reverse this array but leave every 3th element on its position. Meaning I want to get the output like this `5,4,3,2,1,6` but As I inspect variables, in array I have `5,4,2,1,B8`. I have noticed that when program first hits `pop [si]` whole array changes, exploring variables shows me that its `5, NULL, 3, 4, 5, 6` should it not be `5,2,3,4,5,6`? I'm using emu8086. Question may sound silly as I'm new with assembly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three errors :

- You are `pop`ing two bytes into `[si]` but you only need one byte. The solution is to `pop` two bytes into a register and move one byte into `[si]`.
- Under label `n6` you got `loop n5`, but when `cx` becomes zero the `loop` doesn't jump and the block `n7` is executed when it shouldn't.
- You forgot to increase the "3" counter under label `n7`.

Here are the fixes :

```
     n6:
     mov ricxvi, 1
     add si, 1
     loop n5
     jmp finale         ;◄■■ SKIP NEXT BLOCK WHEN CX=0.

     n7:
     add ricxvi, 1      ;◄■■ INCREASE THE "3" COUNTER.
     pop ax             ;◄■■ POP TWO BYTES.
     mov [si], al       ;◄■■ USE ONE BYTE ONLY.
     add si, 1
     loop n5

finale:                 ;◄■■ END LABEL.

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
```